# Edit existing editor inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I want to write custom inspector for one of my scripts. All I want to change is input method for one of the strings to popup (so instead of writing whole string everytime I choose it from premade list of strings, like enums). But the thing is it's VERY long inspector with a lot of variables and rewriting everything just for this one input just doesn't click for me. I'm very happy with how default inspector shows all the fields, expect this one string I want to change. Is there a way to do it without rewriting whole inpector on your own?

Comment: You can get accurate answers on the [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site of the network

Comment: Didn't even know this existed, I'll try my luck there, thanks

Comment: Please post each question on only one site in the StackExchange network, to avoid fragmenting the answers between pages. This helps gather the best solutions in one place where users can more easily survey the options and use votes to highlight the best ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of implementing an entire new Inspector which is a bit overkill as you mentioned you should rather use a [PropertyDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) for that field only.

It depends a lot where you get the available options from. In general I would for example impement a custom [`PropertyAttribute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyAttribute.html)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class SelectionAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public int Index;
}
```

with a custom [`PropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) and place this drawer in a folder called `Editor`

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(SelectionAttribute))]
public class SelectionAttributDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        // The 6 comes from extra spacing between the fields (2px each)
        return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);

        if (property.propertyType != SerializedPropertyType.String)
        {
            EditorGUI.HelpBox(position, "Only works with string", MessageType.Error);
            return;
        }

        //TODO: somewhere you have to get the options from
        var options = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

        if (options == null || options.Length < 1)
        {
            EditorGUI.HelpBox(position, "No options available", MessageType.Error);
            return;
        }

        var selectionAttribute = (SelectionAttribute)attribute;

        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        selectionAttribute.Index = EditorGUI.Popup(position, options.ToList().IndexOf(property.stringValue), options);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            property.stringValue = options[selectionAttribute.Index];
        }

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
```

Now you can use it across your project in multiple classes like e.g.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Selection] public string MySelection;

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(MySelection);
    }
}
```

without the need for a custom editor

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't usage be `[SelectionAttribute] public string MySelection;`?

Comment: @R2RT Nope. You can skip the `Attribute` part in general for all [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/attributes) in c# when using them

Comment: @derHugo If it comes to available options I populate public string array with the names in the inspector (every dialogue has different list of participants) so the options should vary between different dialogues. If you dont mind what's the best way to set options? I tried sending this string array as a parameter to attribute but it needs to be compile time constant so it doesn't work.

Comment: @Bizio I show a way to set the options at runtime at the GameDev.StackExchange copy of this question. I recommend that you edit the copy on that site to ask about changing the list of options per dialogue. That makes the two questions non-duplicates/cross-posts, and lets the existing answers stay where they are.

Comment: @Bizio well I can't see your code ... but in this case I would rather create the property drawer for the dialogues class instead and directly have access to the options then